# How does tag and sender work in c# cant find a fix to my code

Tags: c#, tags, sender

my code below gets an error that says 'object' doesnt contain a definition for 'Tag'. How would i define tag to get this to work.

Im also getting another error saying there is no arguments given that correspond to formal parameter 'sender' and im not sure what this means or how to fix it an have tried googling it but got no where. Any help would be apprieciated.

```
 private void AddNewAppointment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        frmManage frmManage = new frmManage();
        frmManage.dtpDate.Value = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month,(FlowLayoutPanel)sender.Tag);
        frmManage.ShowDialog();
        DisplayCurrentDate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the sender to the expected object type like a label or a texbox or a panel...

From your code it seems there are missing parenthesis:

```
((FlowLayoutPanel)sender).Tag
```

Also you need to cast the `Tag` that is `object`:

```
(int)((FlowLayoutPanel)sender).Tag
```

Also you should write a thing like that to have a code more robust:

```
var panel = sender as FlowLayoutPanel;
if ( panel == null ) throw new Exception("...");
frmManage.dtpDate.Value = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, (int)panel.Tag);
```

Comment: im still getting the error about no arguments responding to the parameter sender in the following code `private void fl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          AddNewAppointment();
        }`

Comment: You need to write `AddNewAppointment(sender, e);`, isn't it?